# Going from VS 2010 Beta 2 to VS 2010 RC in MVC 2 projects causes 'The project type is not supported by this installation.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I just installed VS 2010 RC and now my MVC 2 project created in VS 2010 Beta 2 won't load stating:

> 'The project type is not supported by this installation.'

Sweet!  What the hell do I do now?  Anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read this blog post from Phil Haack? [Installing ASP.NET MVC 2 RC 2 on Visual Studio 2010 RC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/10/installing-asp-net-mvc-2-rc-2-on-visual-studio.aspx)

Depending on the installation order you may have to uninstall/reinstall some components.

Comment: wow - I am screwed on this one, followed blog instructions and now I can't even create a project in VS 2010 RC

Comment: Hrm, bummer.  Have you tried a full uninstall/reinstall?  Might want to file a bug on it... just in case you get lucky and it actually gets fixed in RTM.